# error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ifstream {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>}' and 'int')

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm trying to read several lines of numbers from a text document and I'm not sure which declaration type to use without causing the program to have a fit. Is there a way around this error?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

char studentlettergrade1, StudentGradingFunction1 (int, int, int);
int main()
{
int score1, score2, score3, studentIDnumber1, studentaverage1, num1, num2, num3;

ifstream input;
ofstream output;
// Open Score file
input.open("StudentInfo.txt");
output.open("StudentGrades.txt");

// Read in student scores
while (studentIDnumber1 > 0)
{
   input << studentIDnumber1 << score1 << score2 << score3;
   studentlettergrade1 = StudentGradingFunction1 (score1, score2, score3);
   output << studentIDnumber1 << studentlettergrade1;
}
input.close();
output.close();
}

char StudentGradingFunction1 (int num1, int num2, int num3)
{
   int studentaverage1;
   studentaverage1 = (num1 * .3 + num2 * .3 + num3 * .4) * 100;
   if (studentaverage1 >= 90 && studentaverage <= 100)
   studentlettergrade1 = A;
   else if (studentaverage1 >= 80 && studentaverage1 <= 89.99)
   studentlettergrade1 = B;
   else if (studentaverage1 >= 70 && studentaverage1 <= 79.99)
   studentlettergrade1 = C;
   else if (studentaverage1 >= 60 && studentaverage1 <= 69.99)
   studentlettergrade1 = D;
   else if (studentaverage1 < 60)
   studentlettergrade1 = F;

   return studentlettergrade1;
}
```

EDIT: I've changed my code so the while loop works better, but I'm trying to add a condition for when the program reads a new line that it will register, but the program isn't accepting what I've tried. I tried the following ideas:

```
while ( input >> studentIDnumber1 >> score1 >> score2 >> score3 >> char delim )
{
   studentlettergrade1 = StudentGradingFunction1 (score1, score2, score3);
   output << studentIDnumber1 << studentlettergrade1 << '\n';
}
input.close();
output.close();

cout << "The process has been completed and the grades can be found in StudentGrades.txt " << endl;
}
```

Or this:

```
while ( input >> studentIDnumber1 >> score1 >> score2 >> score3 >> '\n' )
{
   studentlettergrade1 = StudentGradingFunction1 (score1, score2, score3);
   output << studentIDnumber1 << studentlettergrade1 << '\n';
}
input.close();
output.close();

cout << "The process has been completed and the grades can be found in StudentGrades.txt " << endl;
}
```

Neither seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: `input << studentIDnumber1 << score1 << score2 << score3;` should be `input >> studentIDnumber1 >> score1 >> score2 >> score3;` Then there are other errors inside `StudentGradingFunction1`

Comment: Now I'm trying to add a specification to the condition so the program knows that a new line has begun, but I don't know what's the right way to express to the program that a new line has been reached.  `while ( input >> studentIDnumber1 >> score1 >> score2 >> score3 >> char delim )
{
   studentlettergrade1 = StudentGradingFunction1 (score1, score2, score3);
   output << studentIDnumber1 << studentlettergrade1 << '\n';
}
input.close();
output.close();

cout << "The process has been completed and the grades can be found in StudentGrades.txt " << endl;
}`

Comment: `specification to the condition so the program knows that a new line has begun` Sorry but I don't understand what that means. In any case if you have a new question, you should create a new question instead of editting this one.

Comment: If you know exactly how the input file is formatted (say, in this case, every line will have only a single student ID number and exactly 3 scores), then you can read in those 4 values and you will have completed one student. After that, you can simply read in another 4 values (without having to look for any newline characters or anything) and they will correspond to the next student. C++ ifstream understands when a new line has begun, so you do not need to tell it when it occurs. `while(input >> studentIDnumber1 >> score1 >> score2 >> score3)` should be enough.